# A problem about cyclic subspaces and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, cyclic-groups, minimal-polynomials, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

> Let $\alpha$ be a linear operator on a vector space $V$, and supoose that $V$ is $\alpha$-cyclic, say generated by $v\in V$. Suppose further that $V=U_1\bigoplus U_2$ for non-trivial $\alpha$-invariant subspaces $U_1$ and $U_2$ of V.
>
> 1. Prove that both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are $\alpha$-cyclic.
> 2. Suppose further that $\alpha$ has a minimal polynomial $m_\alpha(x)$. Prove that $$m_\alpha(x)=m_{\alpha|_{U_1}}(x)m_{\alpha|_{U_2}}(x).$$

I tried to argue that $U_1$ ($U_2$) is generated by the term of the smallest degree but could not show that either is contained by the cyclic subspace generated. For part 2, I feel like it is intended that we show $m_{\alpha|_{U_1}}(x),m_{\alpha|_{U_2}}(x)$ are coprime do not know how to proceed. Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are in a finite dimensional setting.
For part 1: Let $v = u_1 + u_2$ with $u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in U_2$
I claim that $U_1$ is generated by $u_1, \alpha(u_1), \alpha ² (u_1) ... .$
Let $u \in U_1.$ Since $u \in V$ we can write
$$
u = \sum\limits_i c_i \alpha^i (v) = \sum\limits_i c_i \alpha^i(u_1 + u_2)
= \sum\limits_i c_i \alpha^i (u_1) + \sum\limits_i c_i \alpha^i (u_2).
$$
Since the sum $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$ is direct you have
$u = \sum\limits_i c_i \alpha^i (u_1).$
Same for $U_2$.

For 2: choose a basis for $U_1$ and $U_2$. The union forms a basis for $V$. Now check the matrix representation of $\alpha$ with respect to this basis.

Comment: This question does not assume $V$ to be finite dimensional. In this case how would you approach part 2?

Comment: What is the definition of minimal polynomial in this case? Also you need to assume that $U_1, U_2$ are $\alpha$-invariant. Otherwise you can easily find a counterexample to part 1

Comment: The monic polynomial of the least degree that $\alpha$ satisfies, this polynomial is also unique.

Comment: assume that $m_{\alpha} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n c_i x^i$ with $f(\alpha) = 0$. Then $0 = f(\alpha)(v) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n c_i \alpha^i (v) $. From that it follows $c_n \alpha^n(v) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n-1} c_i \alpha^i (v)$. That means that $v, \alpha(v), \ldots, \alpha^n (v)$ are not linear independent. Since they generate $V$ its dimension is less then $n$